# Passing Dictionary<string, object> to AWS Lambda serializes it to Dictionary<string, JsonElement>

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, system.text.json

My AWS Step Function passes a custom object from Lambda to Lambda.  One of the properties on this object is a `Dictionary<string, object>` -- but the AWS JSON serializer turns into something like `Dictionary<string, JsonElement>`.   So if I pass an object to it that Newtonsoft would deserialize like so:

```json
{ "name": "Tom", "age": 99, "married": true }
```

...what the Lambda receives as the input parameter is like so:

```json
{
    "name" : { "ValueKind": 3 }, 
    "age"  : { "ValueKind": 2 },
    "married" : {"ValueKind: 1 }
}
```

(Ignore my ValueKind values, they aren't important.)

This means that the input to my Lambda is unusable.

I don't want to write and maintain a pile of translator code to tick thru every entry in the Dictionary and reconstitute it, for all 10+ Lambdas in my Step Function.  (I'm not sure I can, anyway.  I presume when it's deserialized like this the original value is lost.)

Suggestions?  Can I swap out the Amazon JSON Serializer for Newtonsoft's?  Can I create an extension that will help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I've found was [this from Josef Ottosson](https://josef.codes/custom-dictionary-string-object-jsonconverter-for-system-text-json/).

I tried making my own Dictionary, that would interrogate every new Key/Value pair and put each entry into an internal strings-only dictionary, or longs-only dictionary, and so avoid storing any data as `object`.  But nothing worked.

To my delight the article lands dead-center in my problem space:  How to de/serialize objects with `Dictionary<string, object>` properties.  He created a `JsonConverterAttribute` that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I swap out the Amazon JSON Serializer for Newtonsoft's?

It looks like you can - looking at [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html):

> Unless your function input and output parameters are of type System.IO.Stream, you will need to serialize them. AWS Lambda provides a default serializer that can be applied at the assembly or method level of your application, or you can define your own by implementing the ILambdaSerializer interface provided by the Amazon.Lambda.Core library. For more information, see [Deploy C# Lambda functions with .zip file archives](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-package.html).

> To add the default serializer attribute to a method, first add a dependency on Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json in your .csproj file.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <AssemblyName>AssemblyName</AssemblyName>
    </PropertyGroup>
      
    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json" Version="1.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

They also include an example of how to dictate what method uses what serializer:

```
public class ProductService{
    [LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
    public Product DescribeProduct(DescribeProductRequest request)
    {
      return catalogService.DescribeProduct(request.Id);
    }
   
   [LambdaSerializer(typeof(MyJsonSerializer))]
   public Customer DescribeCustomer(DescribeCustomerRequest request)
   {
      return customerService.DescribeCustomer(request.Id);
   }
}
```

They also recommend for .NET Core 3.1 projects (and up presumably), that you use [their serializer](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson) which makes use of `System.Text.Json` in order to minimize cold start performance:

> If targeting .NET Core 3.1 this serializer is highly recommend over Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json and can significantly reduce cold start performance in Lambda.

Comment: Many thanks!  I figured there was a way, but backed off.  Worried I'd spend a day chasing this and find it had a dozen weird side effects.